# Uncommon syntax? ---"->"

Tags: syntax

I was looking at someone else's code and saw something that I'd only been told was a pointer. The thing is the syntax is not pointer syntax. This is the following code:

```
switch(control)
  {
      case 'w':
      case 'a':
      case 's':
      case 'd':
          execute->backup_grid();// this is the part I was talking about.
          execute->fill_space();
          execute->update_grid();
          execute->fill_space();
          execute->find_greatest_tile();
          execute->display_grid();


          if(execute->full()&&apocalypse)
          {
              response=-1;
              break;
          }
          else if(execute->block_moves())
          {
              execute->spawn();
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              response=0;
              break;
          }
```

Comment: Why do you believe this is not pointer syntax?

Comment: If this is C syntax, and it looks like it is, `->` *is* the correct pointer to element syntax, @LEXERA.EXE

Comment: because pointer syntax is different than this. But basically what I'm saying is I don't believe this is how pointers are used correct? Which would lead me to believe that it's not a pointer. Also c++ pointer use is like this if I'm mistaken?: int myPointer = 1 ;  int *my2ndPointer = &myPointer

Comment: This is c++ syntax @BrianTiffin

Comment: I'm running it in a c++ compiler. my only conclusion is that my compiler supports both C and C++ syntax.

Comment: just to be sure @LEXERA.EXE can you post class/struct related to `execute`?

Comment: I'm sorry @BagusTesa all the code is to big to big for me to just comment that one class. Also sorry I didn't get back to you earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

That is a kind of pointer syntax. In plain C, if you have a pointer to a struct, you can access the value of a member with the "arrow" operator, like this:

```
struct foo {
    int num ; 
}; 
struct foo var ; 
struct foo *ptr ; 
var.num = 0; 
ptr = &var; 
printf("%d ", ptr->num); // 0 
printf("%d ", (*ptr).num); //0
```

In essence

```
ptr->num
```

is a shorter way of

```
 (*ptr)->num
```

In your code, you are calling methods with a pointer to some object.

Comment: Oh , thanks now I understand it. That actually blew my mind!